# how can i load <script>'s into an iframe?

Tags: javascript, jquery, iframe

I've got the logic working to append into my iframe from the parent

this works:

```
$('#iframe').load(function() {
  $(this).contents().find('#target').append('this text has been inserted into the iframe by jquery');    
});
```

this doesn't

```
$('#iframe').load(function() {
  $(this).contents().find('body').append('<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js"></script>');    
});
```

.lf

*The problem is something to do with the inserted script tags not being escaped properly.
Half of the javascript is becomes visible in the html, like the first script tag has been abruptly ended.*

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Maybe the error is with your string, never create a string in javascript with a literal **< /script>** in it.

```
$('#iframe').load(function() {
  $(this).contents().find('body').append('<scr' + 'ipt type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js"></scr' + 'ipt>');    
});
```

Comment: Gah! How could I miss that?! I even pointed it out to someone else in another question (not on SO) *earlier today*. Wish I could +2 this.

Comment: *"...never create a string with..."* Well, *creating* it (as you have done) is fine. It's having the literal one there that's the problem.

Comment: i was nearly there in the question "The problem is something to do with the inserted script tags not being escaped properly" haha, thanks guys

Answer (score 12):

<s>I'm a bit surprised that isn't working</s> *[Edit: No longer surprised at all, see [mtrovo's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3935398/how-can-i-load-scripts-into-an-iframe/3935797#3935797).]*...but here's what I do, which is <s>mostly</s> non-jQuery per your comment below but still quite brief:

```
var rawframe = document.getElementById('theframe');
var framedoc = rawframe.contentDocument;
if (!framedoc && rawframe.contentWindow) {
    framedoc = rawframe.contentWindow.document;
}
var script = doc.createElement('script');
script.type = "text/javascript";
script.src = "http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js";
framedoc.body.appendChild(script);
```

Off-topic: I **really** wouldn't give an iframe (or anything else) the ID "iframe". That just feels like it's asking for trouble (IE has namespace issues, and while I'm not aware of it confusing tag names and IDs, I wouldn't be completely shocked). I've used "theframe" above instead.

Comment: Thanks TJ, this is looking good, I've just come across the problem that i need to load jquery into the iframe, without using jquery to do so. (because jquery isn't yet loaded into the iframe to do the loading) !     - is it easy to do this in pure js?

Comment: @Haroldo: Yes. In fact, the answer was pure JavaScript except for the first line. I've modified the first line so it's pure JavaScript. But you can use jQuery to do the load, provided jQuery is loaded in the window your code is running in (as opposed to the iframe's window). But I think mtrovo has pointed out why your original code wasn't working, see [his/her answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3935398/how-can-i-load-scripts-into-an-iframe/3935797#3935797) for more.

Comment: "document.body.appendChild(script);" must be "doc.body.appendChild(script);" right!?

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Ahh! "frame.body.appendChild(script);" must be "framedoc.body.appendChild(script);" right!? Must be a typo.

Answer (score 5):

Warning: loading script in this manner would make scripts running in main window context
i.e.: if you use window from somescript.js, it would be **NOT** iframe's window!

```
$('#iframe').load(function() {
    $(this).contents().find('body').append('<scr' + 'ipt type="text/javascript" src="somescript.js"></scr' + 'ipt>');    
});
```

To be able to use iframe context inject script with this:

```
function insertScript(doc, target, src, callback) {
    var s = doc.createElement("script");
    s.type = "text/javascript";
    if(callback) {
        if (s.readyState){  //IE
            s.onreadystatechange = function(){
                if (s.readyState == "loaded" ||
                    s.readyState == "complete"){
                    s.onreadystatechange = null;
                    callback();
                }
            };
        } else {  //Others
            s.onload = function(){
                callback();
            };
        }
    }
    s.src = src;
    target.appendChild(s);        
}

var elFrame = document.getElementById('#iframe');
$(elFrame).load(function(){
    var context = this.contentDocument;
    var frameHead = context.getElementsByTagName('head').item(0);
    insertScript(context, frameHead, '/js/somescript.js');
}
```

Comment: accessing the iframe's document makes a lot of sense. Can you talk more about what the `.load` function is doing? I don't see that syntax in their docs

Comment: .load(function() {}...) is the complete callback for when the iframe is done loading: http://api.jquery.com/load/