# Script not running on a page opened in a frame

Tags: javascript, html

I have a page that runs a script when I press a button. It works when the page is opened in a separate window, but when i open that page inside a frame of other page, nothing is happening when I click on the same button. What could be the problem?

Code:

```
<form class="inout">
Input:<br>
<textarea rows="4" cols="50" id="in"></textarea>
</form>


<form class="inout">
Output:<br>
<textarea rows="4" cols="50" id="out" readonly></textarea>
</form>

<br>
<button id="btn" onclick="rucsac();" >Ruleaza!</button>
```

And the script is declared in head:

```
<script src="probleme.js"></script>
```

As is said, it runs properly when is individualy opened, but in frame it does not work. (I use Chrome)
And the script:

```
function read(params)
{
var mytext= document.getElementById("in").value;
var i=0,l=0;
while(i<mytext.length)
{
    var nr=0;
    while(mytext[i]>='0'&&mytext[i]<='9'&&i<mytext.length)
    {
        nr=nr*10+(mytext[i]-'0');
        i++;
    }
    params[l++]=nr;
    while(!(mytext[i]>='0'&&mytext[i]<='9')&&i<mytext.length) 
    {
        if((mytext[i]>='a'&&mytext[i]<='z')||(mytext[i]>='A'&&mytext[i]<='Z')) return 0;
        i++;
    }
}
}
function rucsac()
{
var v = new Array();
document.getElementById("out").value="";
if(read(v)==0)
{
 document.getElementById("out").value="Datele de intrare contin caractere necorespunzatoare!";
 return 0;
}
if(v.length===0)
{
document.getElementById("out").value="Cititi datele inainte de rulare!";
 return 0;
}
var n=v[0],g=v[1];
if(v.length<n+2)
{
document.getElementById("out").value="Date incomplete!";
 return 0;

}
var i,j,l=1,MAX=0;
var w= new Array(100001), p=new Array(100001), pf=new Array(100001).fill(0);
   for(i=1;i<=n;i++)
        {
    w[i]=v[++l];
    p[i]=v[++l];
    }

    for(i=1;i<=n;i++)
        for(j=g-w[i];j>=0;j--)
          if(pf[j+w[i]]<pf[j]+p[i])
    {
        pf[j+w[i]]=pf[j]+p[i];
        if(pf[j+w[i]]>MAX) MAX=pf[j+w[i]];
    }
document.getElementById("out").value+=MAX;
}
```

Comment: Share your `Probleme.js` file code.

Comment: P.S - Frames are [obsolete](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTML_element#Frames) in HTML5 and are discouraged to use.

Comment: It's an iframe, I know that this one is allowed...

Comment: First take a look here - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3935398/how-can-i-load-scripts-into-an-iframe
Second - as @piarte X wrote, frames are dangerous to use (xss issues) so try to avoid them when possible

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Declare your `<script src="probleme.js"></script>` inside the iframe tag as well. I believe it is currently residing in the `<head>` tag of the main webpage right now.

You are seeing this problem because the parent JS is not able to access the events inside the iframe. You should include the script inside the source of the iframe.

Comment: *"inside the iframe tag"* is a very misleading statement. It implies `<iframe><script></script></iframe>` which is usesless