# JS & jQuery script inside iframe function as if from parent html

Tags: javascript, jquery, iframe

The below code is in a script which has been loaded into the iframe `#contframe` source html. The button is inside the iframe.

Why does this only work when I reference the function as if it is coming from the parent HTML?

For example, the below code works:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  var kuf = $('#contframe').contents().find('#zbtn');
  kuf.click(function() {
    alert("hello");  
  });
});
```

However the below function does not work at all:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#zbtn').click(function() {
    alert("oi");
  });
});
```

Comment: It's because the content of an iframe is a completely different DOM to the parent page. This is why you need to access it through `contents()`

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan: OP seems to imply that this code is loaded in the iframe. Not sure though.

Comment: True, it states the button is in the iframe, but doesn't state the location of the JS. Given the working use of `contents()` I can only assume it's in the parent page.

Comment: The script is not inside the original html.

Comment: Perhaps if you didn't edit my question so much it would make sense.
The script runs from inside the iframe.

Comment: Your original question was unreadable

Comment: Was it pretty? No.
But it was perfectly legible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was completely appending my scripts; I believe using the doc.createElement fixed the issue.

The following solved my issue - some slight edits from Andriy F. https://stackoverflow.com/a/13344966/10824788

```
//CREATES NEW JS & CSS TAGS RESPECTIVELY
function insertScript(doc, target, src, callback) {
var insertjs = doc.createElement("script");
insertjs.type = "text/javascript";
insertjs.src = src;
target.appendChild(insertjs);
}
function insertCss(doc, target, href, callback) {
var insertcss = doc.createElement("link");
insertcss.type = "text/css";
insertcss.rel = "stylesheet";
insertcss.href = href;
target.appendChild(insertcss);    
}

//ADDS ABOVE TO IFRAME
$('#contframe').on('load', function(){
var context = this.contentDocument;
var frameHead = context.getElementsByTagName('head').item(0);
insertScript(context, frameHead, '/scripts/jquery.min.js');
insertScript(context, frameHead, '/scripts/content.js');
insertCss(context, frameHead, '/scripts/content.css');
});
```