# Loading same script into multiple iframes - efficiency while maintaining context?

Tags: javascript, dom, iframe

I have a parent page with multiple iframes.

I need to load `<script type="text/javascript" src="/example.js">` into all iframes. The script is the same.

When loaded, the context for the script needs to be each respective iframe.

When I run the below code against each iframe, it seems to work, except `/example.js` seems to be fetched `n` times, where `n` is how many iframes there are.

```
let iframeScript = iframe.contentWindow.document.createElement('script');
iframeScript.src = '/example.js';
iframeScript.type = 'text/javascript';
iframe.contentWindow.document.head.appendChild(iframeScript);
```

If I load the script inside the main window and then copy the node into all iframes, then, predictably, it's loaded once for the main window: the `window` context inside the script refers to the main window, and the script is executed only once.

How do I fetch the script only once while maintaining the context of each iframe, and executing the script against each iframe?

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3935398/how-can-i-load-scripts-into-an-iframe